# JavaFX приложение есть много памяти

Tags: java, javafx, память

Написал приложение на JavaFX которое через webengine парсит страницы, потом с помощью jsoup берутся значения элементов и выводятся в таблицу. Проблема в том, что чем больше работает приложение, тем больше оно съедает оперативки (через пару часов работы может съесть под 8 гб). Запускал с jprofiler, но все параметры вроде в норме и куча не увеличивается. Не понимаю в чем проблема

[image: jprofiler]

Comment: Дебаг режим пробовали? 
Посмотрите что у вас в циклах творится, правильно ли закрывается соединение, не используете ли вы String в циклах?

Comment: Сам код возможно увидеть? У вас явная утечка

Comment: @GenCloud, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Bsa-UzKnsUbGU3ZURRbzFPUVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Операционная система не Unix-like случайно?

Comment: @AndreyM, нет, windows 7

Comment: @mckay Нет так нет, а спросил я потому что сталкивался с жуткими утечками в нативном коде рендерера и помогло переключение на совтверный `-Dprism.order=sw `; но это под последней Debian с Intelовской карточкой

Comment: @alexandrgaiduchok, видимо проблема со String, т.к в первой части программы он не используется и потребление памяти не увеличивается, а как в дело вступает работа с ним, то график потребления начинает ползти вверх. В конце цикла я к переменным присваиваю null, но толку от этого столько же. String заменить на char или на что либо еще, или что то можно сделать чтобы String не съедал память?

Comment: @mckay Уберите отовсюду .intern()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема частично решилась установкой размера истории движка на 0

engine.getHistory().setMaxSize(0);

В моем случаи после холодного старта, 20 мин работы программы, потребляют вместо ~1gb, ~830mb. Но все равно, чем дольше работает программа, тем больше она потребляет.

upd: проблема кроется в jdk8. При загрузке большого кол-ва страниц у WebEngine происходит заметная утечка памяти. В jdk9 проблема решена

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из кода:

Утечка памяти у вас находится в PermGen(jdk 1.7) или Metaspace(jdk 1.8) из-за неправильного использования intern()

> https://habrahabr.ru/post/79913/
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning

Второй момент: Jsoup сам прекрасно справляется с получением страницы, если вам нужен кроме получения станицы WebEngine больше не нужен то лучше использовать только Jsoup

> https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url

Третий момент:

```
        doc = null;
        state = null;
        interests = null;
        name = null;
        str = null;
        city = null;
        lastActivity = null;
        age = 0;
        iAmt = 0;
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            rt.exec("free -m");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Уберите и этот кусок кода. Причина - обнуление здесь не поможет, обнуление примитивов тем более, ручной вызов gc не поможет.

> http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

Попробуйте установить
-XX:MaxPermSize=???m чтобы проверить переполнение perm gen

Comment: Тот код уже был устаревшим. Сейчас внес изменения в документе по ссылке. Дало небольшой эффект после установки размера истории движка на 0. Объем потребления растет, но не так интенсивно, значит видимо основная утечка это не история. Убрал intern(). Я бы и рад пользоваться только jsoup, но на сколько я знаю, он не работает с js на сайте. Metaspace в районе 30mb. Обнуления конечно да, не дают толка, но если не вызывать gc, то потребление сразу растет до ~1.7 gb, против 400-500 mb

Comment: @mckay так что дало профит? изменение размера истории или intern()? Очень интересно....

Comment: Размер истории. В самом начале у меня было без intern(), потом нашел информацию что вроде как intern() может помочь решить проблему, но толку все равно не было. Но один фиг, даже с нулевой историей, пара часов работы и оперативе конец.

Comment: @mckay Оформите в виде ответа, чтобы те у кого будет подобный вопрос не искали в комментариях. Спасибо